# Java default string hash function produces collisions on single character strings

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I am a CS student, so please bear with me if what I say sounds too ridiculous. It definitely does so to me, that is why I am here in search of an answer.
I read how strings are hashed in Java, and then I took a look at the ASCII table. The letters "d" and "n" hash to 100 and 110 respectively. Now if I were to create a brand new hashmap in Java, by default it has 10 buckets. So even though the hashcodes are unique, mod 10 they are both 0. This leads to a collision. 
Having collision on 1 character strings just doesn't sit well with me, so is the process I described correct? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

What you described is probably correct, both would fall on the same bucket due to the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), which basically means that if you have more items than holes to put them on, two or more will end up on the same hole. In this case, considering only the 95 printable [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters, the principle states that there would be at least 10 in each hole (not considering the actual values, only the amount of them).

However, shazin's answer is also correct in that the hash values are not actually used as the identity for the values in a map, instead they are used to find the bucket in which the kay/value pair belongs, and then values in the bucket are checked for equality with their `equals()` method (or with `==`, if using `IdentityHashMap`.)

Comment: +1 for the pidgeon hole principle. It would be impressive to come up with a hash function that can place each single character in a unique bucket when there are only 10 buckets...

Comment: Java's load factor of 0.75 increases the number of buckets as we add more elements, it isn't as if we add all 95 elements while the number of buckets remains a constant 10.

Comment: That' true, however the point still remains that given a domain larger than the initial bucket count, there are bound to be collisions on the first elements

Answer (score 3):

Hash is actually used in Hash based collections as an index or grouping mechanism. Hash is not used as an actual reference. Hash used to find the bucket in which the element may contain first.

As you said `d` and `n` can be contained in the same bucket but after that the actual value in this case `d` and `n` can be used to refer the actual object. Since Hashmaps don't allow duplicate keys you can be sure that there will always be one `d` and one `n`.

Comment: but ideally (if there are no collisions), every bucket contains a single pair (key, value) correct? So the fact that `d` and `n` both end up in the same bucket is a collision by definition. Isn't this correct?

Comment: Although now that I think about it, if I insert more elements into the map, exceeding the load factor, more buckets will be added, less and less single characters will end up in one bucket, eventually resulting in each character having their own buckets.

Comment: @user96454: good insight re. some early-colliding elements being separated as the table grows, but do note that some statistically-lesser number of keys may be newly collided by rehashing after growth, and that you can't statistically *expect* (i.e. > 50% chance) there to be no collisions unless the number of buckets is *massively* larger than the number of keys - massively due to the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) - and that would be so wasteful of memory it's worse than a few collisions.  In the general case, you must expect some collisions.